# Can't figure out why every query returns else (case when)

Tags: mysql

I'm writing this code in a PHP variable where the $username and $email get replaced. I echo this to the screen and it looked right. I'm assuming there is an issue with the MySQL code because the only result I always get back is 'acceptable'. Any help?

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN email='$email' THEN '$email is already associated with an account' 
WHEN username='$username' THEN '$username is already taken' 
ELSE 'acceptable' 
END AS result FROM collaborator 
UNION 
SELECT CASE 
WHEN email='$email' THEN '$email is already associated with an account' 
WHEN username='$username' THEN '$username is already taken' 
ELSE 'acceptable' 
END AS result 
FROM waitForValidation 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Possibly a case sensitivity issue? and in all cases will the union return a result of not 'acceptable'? and thus the order returned could be variable returning limit 1 eliminating the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is a failure to match in one or the other table, so `'acceptable'` is coming from somewhere.  Then, you are using `union`, which removes duplicates -- typically by ordering.  Try doing the match in a different way:

```
select (case when max(email) = $email then '$email is already associated with an account' 
             when max(username)='$username' THEN '$username is already taken'
             else 'acceptable'
        end)
from (select email, username
      from collaborator
      where email = '$email' or username= '$username'
      union
      select email, username
      from waitForValidation 
      where email = '$email' or username= '$username'
     ) t
```

This uses `max()` instead of `limit` to handle the case when there are no matches.  In this case, the `max()` will return `NULL`, so the first two conditions will fail.